# RuntimeError: unable to perform operation on TCPTransport the handler is closed

Tags: python, gunicorn, fastapi, starlette, uvicorn

I'm trying to make an HTTP benchmark test on my local machine with `autocannon` tool to my fresh, brand-new project setup that I've built on `FastAPI` + `uvicorn`.

But at some point or randomly (I don't know what's happening) I'm having an ASGI exception.

```
[2019-11-14 14:16:40 +0100] [98098] [ERROR] Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/yigidix/Projects/url_shortener/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 385, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "/Users/yigidix/Projects/url_shortener/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 45, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/yigidix/Projects/url_shortener/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 139, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/yigidix/Projects/url_shortener/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 134, in __call__
    await self.error_middleware(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/yigidix/Projects/url_shortener/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 178, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/Users/yigidix/Projects/url_shortener/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 156, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/Users/yigidix/Projects/url_shortener/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 73, in __call__
    raise exc from None
  File "/Users/yigidix/Projects/url_shortener/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 62, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/Users/yigidix/Projects/url_shortener/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 590, in __call__
    await route(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/yigidix/Projects/url_shortener/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 208, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/yigidix/Projects/url_shortener/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 44, in app
    await response(scope, receive, send)
  File "/Users/yigidix/Projects/url_shortener/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/responses.py", line 125, in __call__
    "headers": self.raw_headers,
  File "/Users/yigidix/Projects/url_shortener/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 59, in sender
    await send(message)
  File "/Users/yigidix/Projects/url_shortener/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 153, in _send
    await send(message)
  File "/Users/yigidix/Projects/url_shortener/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 482, in send
    self.transport.write(b"".join(content))
  File "uvloop/handles/stream.pyx", line 673, in uvloop.loop.UVStream.write
  File "uvloop/handles/handle.pyx", line 159, in uvloop.loop.UVHandle._ensure_alive
RuntimeError: unable to perform operation on <TCPTransport closed=True reading=False 0x7fb255569780>; the handler is closed
```

To start my application, I do:

```
gunicorn url_shortener:app -w 1 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
```

> I tried to raise the number of the workers. I still get these exceptions.

To benchmark test, I do:

```
autocannon -c 100 -d 40 -p 10 localhost:8000/shorten -H "Content-Type: application/json" -m POST -b '{"url": "http://yigitgenc.com"}'
```

P.S: My database (`PostgreSQL`) works on `Docker` container. And also I do async database interactions (for sure). Maybe adding this info would be helpful.

Comment: I think it happens because of your database connection is closed by the server or a TCP timeout while it's in the pool. which version of asyncpg are you using? Can you add how do you connect database? Did you tried to run with pure uvicorn instead of using  uvicornWorkers?

Comment: did you find the answer to this problem ?

Comment: I am getting this error when I pipeline requests, to uvicorn using uvloop to run fastapi.

Comment: Maybe the connection is being closed from the client side due to timeouts. Then when gunicorn tries to write a response, the socket is closed